# ClickOnce Error "different computed hash than specified in manifest" when transferring published files

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I am in an interesting situation where I maintain the code for a program that is used and distributed primarily by our sister company.  We are ready to distribute the program to all of the 3rd party users and since it is technically our sister companies program, we want to host it on their website.  (in the interest of anonimity, I'll use 'program' everywhere instead of the actual application name, and 'www.SisterCompany.com' instead of their actual URL.)

So I get everything ready to go, setup the Publish setting to check for updates at program start, the minimum required version, and I set the Insallation Folder URL and Update Location to "http://www.SisterCompany.com/apps/program/", with the actual Publishing Folder Location as "C:\LocalProjects\Program\Publish\".  Everything else is pretty standard.

After publish, I confirm that everything installs and works correctly when running directly from the publish location on my C: drive.  So I put everything on our FTP server, and the guy at our sister company pulls it down and places everything in the '/apps/program/' directory on their webserver.

This is where it goes bad.  When I try to install it from their site, I get the `- File, Program.exe.config, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.` Error.  I tested it a bit, and I even get that error trying to install from any network location on our network other than my local C: drive.

After doing the initial publish in visual studio, I have changed no files (which is the answer/reason I've found by doing some searching about this error).

What could be causing this?  Is it because I set the Installation Folder URL to a location that it isn't initially published too?

Let me know if any additional info is needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After bashing my head against this all weekend, I have finally found the answer.  After unsigning the project and removing the hash on the offending file (an xml file), I got the program to install, but it was giving me 'Windows Side by Side' Errors.  I drilled down into the App Cache were the file was, and instead of a config .xml file, it was one of the HTML files from the website the clickonce installer was hosted on.  Turns out that the web server didn't seem to like serving up an .XML (or .mdb it turns out) file.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228998.aspx) ended up giving me the final solution:

**I had to make sure that the 'Use ".deploy" file extension' was selected so that the web server wouldn't mangle files with extensions it didn't like.**

[image]

I couldn't figure out why that one file's hash would be different.  Turns out it wasn't even the same file at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that one of the FTP transfers is happening in text mode, rather than binary?

Comment: That's a good thought, and at first I suspected that it was the FTP transfer that was messing with things.  However, I get the same error by just copying the publish folder to any shared network drive on our internal network.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that .config transformations were done after generating manifest.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else who's still having trouble, five years later:

The first problem was configuring the MIME type, which on nginx (/etc/nginx/mime.types) should look like this:

```
    application/x-ms-manifest       application
```

See [Click Once Server and Client Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/server-and-client-configuration-issues-in-clickonce-deployments).

The weirder problem to me was that I was using git to handle the push to the server, i.e.

```
    git remote add live ssh://user@mybox/path/to/publish
    git commit -am "committing...";git push live master
```

Works great for most things, but it was probably being registered as a "change," which prevented the app from installing locally. Once I started using scp instead:

```
   scp -r * user@mybox/path/to/dir/
```

It worked without a hitch.

It is unfortunate that there is not a lot of helpful information out there about this.